# MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate not working Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have been using the mail composer in a few of my apps for awhile now and as of recent the mailComposeDelegate no longer gets call.
I wasn't sure if this was something to do with the new release of Swift.
 So, I thought I would ask and see if anyone else is having similar issues.
I can present the mail composer but it never gets dismissed due to the delegate not working.

Below is an exact copy of the code I have been using:

```
func launchFeedback() {
    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
        return
    }

    let emailTitle = "Feedback"
    let messageBody = ""
    let toRecipents = ["johnappleseed@icloud.com"]
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposer.setSubject(emailTitle)
    mailComposer.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
    mailComposer.setToRecipients(toRecipents)
    self.show(mailComposer, sender: self)
}

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    print(error)
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is clearly an Xcode bug. The only way to get around this (after searching though StackOverflow life for an hour) was this:

```
    @objc(mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:)
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult,error: NSError?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
```

See the @objc macro before the method implementation. Also note that the last parameter has to be NSError type instead of Error as suggested by Apple documentation (and autocompleted by Xcode)

Comment: If this is really an XCode bug, it still exists in 10.3, when you calculate your attachments on a background thread, and use another view controller for progress, that displays the compose controller at dismiss. But this answer still resolves it, so a big upvote to it!

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 no longer has unnamed first parameters by default (see [this proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md)), so you'll need to add an underscore to your function:

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    print(error)
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4, Xcode 9.1.** 
My issue was that `MFMailComposeViewController` was working fine but if you click cancel, dismiss, and then trying to open it one more time both cancel and send button will not fire `didFinishWith` delegate function.
It was happening because I've declared `MFMailComposeViewController` as lazy variable and solution was to create new instance of `MFMailComposeViewController` every time you want to open it.

Problem:

```
lazy var mailComposeViewController: MFMailComposeViewController = {
    let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposeViewController.setToRecipients(["example@test.test"])
    mailComposeViewController.setSubject("subject")
    mailComposeViewController.setMessageBody("test body", isHTML: false)
    return mailComposeViewController
}()
```

Solution:

```
func createMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposeViewController.setToRecipients(["example@test.test"])
    mailComposeViewController.setSubject("subject")
    mailComposeViewController.setMessageBody("test body", isHTML: false)
    return mailComposeViewController
}
```

Comment: This was about to make my brain explode.  So obvious now that I know it!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

After wasting 2 good hours, i came to the conclusion that as of Xcode 8.3. MFMailComposeViewController does not work on a mixed swift/objc code base. It pops odd compile errors, which first i thought were due to my stupidity, but no.

This is so frustrating apple. Most of us old timers do have tons of code on obj-c, so a pure swift scenario is close to impossible. So as i move classes to swift i have to deal with extra pain as well.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

to the `AppName-Bridging-Header.h` did the job !